Domain folder and target class not showing but application is running smoothly
I have a problem with Java Spring Boot application finding a file let's call it appservice. The application works and is running smoothly however I am having trouble finding a certain class file, particularly, com.app.appservice.domain.appSegments.
I can see other classes under the parent repository such as com.app.appservice.service.transformapp.zoms.Utilities. but not classes that has com.app.appservice.domain.
I also check and there is no domain folder.
I need to edit this class since I have issues setting a new field instantiated in this class.

I am not sure what you want us to do about it? :) If the file is there edit it. If it is not there create it and then edit it. 3. If it is there but IDE doesn't show it give us more info regarding which IDE doesn't work under which conditions

The domain folder might not be under the main directory. It might be a generated source directory under the build folder or under some other folder. What IDE are you running? In IntelliJ IDEA, press shift+ctrl+N and type the name of the file.

Maybe you can't see it in the structure of your domain folder because it comes from a different package in your pom.xml.
